# Union types in Java

Tags: java, c#, kotlin, discriminated-union

I've been working with C# for a while and trying to get more familiar with Java. So I'm trying to migrate some of the basic patterns I use on daily basis in C# even only to understand the gap between JVM and dotnet and figure out how to deal with them. Here is the first problem I encountered - an option type - somethiong which is quite easy to achieve in many languages i.e. Koltlin:

```
sealed class Option<out T : Any> {
    object None : Option<Nothing>()
    data class Some<out T : Any>(val value: T) : Option<T>()}
```

so I can easily create a map functor:

```
fun <T : Any, B : Any> Option<T>.map(f: (T) -> B): Option<B> =
    when (this) {
        is Option.None -> Option.None
        is Option.Some -> Option.Some(f(this.value))}
```

Is this something I can achieve in Java? Im not concerned about the lack of extentions methods, I can live without that, but how to perform the actual type matching without having to rely on an unchecked cast? At least thats what IntelliJ is complaining about...

Comment: You are asking about Java, but show no Java code. I feel this isn't right.

Comment: Neither C# nor Java have union types, and any workarounds will be awkward to use at best. For a .NET language that does have union types, please look at F#.

Comment: Looks perhaps like you are looking for [java.util.Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) from Java 8.

Comment: There isn't anything exactly equivalent - but why do you need a Java solution, when you already have one in Kotlin, which has perfectly working interop?

Comment: @dumetrulo, you can easily simulate union types in C# without much typing, not as cleanly as in F# but perfectly usable, you can also do pattern-match generic types which is rather difficult in Java due to generic types erasure. The question how to achieve the same in Java.

Comment: @Moira, you are right, unfortunately Java is the only approved JVM technology at my worklplace.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon, I seems like the java.util.Optional should do the job in case of the Option/Maybe type. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Thanks All, I guess I'll need to start my Java learning excersise with something more down-to-the-earth.

Answer (score 17):

in the specific case you mentioned, the following would work:

- (as @oldcurmudgeon mentioned) [`java.util.Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) it also has [a `map` function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#map-java.util.function.Function-).
- there's also the guava library, that has [`com.google.common.base.Optional`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Optional.html), in case you want it for java version 7 and below. the equivalent of `map` here would be [the `transform` function](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Optional.html#transform(com.google.common.base.Function)).

Java doesn't have pattern matching. The closest you can get to pattern matching in Java is with [the visitor pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/visitor).

usage:

```java
UnionType unionType = new TypeA();
    
Integer count = unionType.when(new UnionType.Cases<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public Integer is(TypeA typeA) {
        // TypeA-specific handling code
    }

    @Override
    public Integer is(TypeB typeB) {
        // TypeB-specific handling code
    }
});
```

boilerplate code:

```java
interface UnionType {
    <R> R when(Cases<R> c);
    
    interface Cases<R> {
        R is(TypeA typeA);
    
        R is(TypeB typeB);
    }
}
    
class TypeA implements UnionType {

    // ... TypeA-specific code ...

    @Override
    public <R> R when(Cases<R> cases) {
        return cases.is(this);
    }
}
    
class TypeB implements UnionType {

    // ... TypeB-specific code ...

    @Override
    public <R> R when(Cases<R> cases) {
        return cases.is(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Strikes me as hard to read and reason with, compared to some syntactic union type support.

Comment: @dlamblin , i agree. I wrote this up a while ago when Java didn't have native union type support. I'm not sure if Java has union type support not or not now though

Comment: I was trying to find out, it seems not as yet no.

Comment: There is a preview feature to get pattern matching in Java, based on switch expressions: https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/406 - seems quite comprehensive for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

When I bumped into this, my function needed to handle `double[]` or `String[]`. So I always passed both (setting the non-existing one to `null`) and the function was something like

```
public void myFunc(String[] valuesCategorical, double[] valuesNumeric){
    if (valuesCategorical == null){
        doSomethingWithCategorical(valuesCategorical);
    } else {
        doSomethingWithNumeric(valuesNumeric);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use overloads in such case?

Comment: @solru Do you mean defining `doSomething(String[] values)` and `doSomething(double[] values)`? In my case, completely valid solution, but both do-something methods were different enough to deserve different names (IMO). However, if you mean defining `myFunc(String[] values)` and `myFunc(double[] values)`, that was undesirable, because I would end-up with "two copies" of the same function (my acual `myFunc` does more than just the if-else above)

Comment: I fail to understand how this solves the problem. You will still need to know what you are working with beforehand... And in any case, this function is really bad design-wise since it aggregates multiple responsibilities of different actions into one method (which makes it harder to use, extend, and change in the future)